# Good practice, javascript blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, playframework

Im using Playframework 2.2 for an app and im using a lot of ajax to load content.

Sometimes when i load content via ajax i want to bind/change an event handler, lets say the click handler for a anchor that was just retrived, to do this i always put a block like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#anchorId').click(function(e){
        object.removeAdmin('someId'); //object is based on a prototype
    });
</script>
```

My questions are ¿Its a good practice to write the javascript block inside the html? ¿Its better to remove it after it execution? ¿Is there different way to bind the handler to the object/s?

I know it's not bad, but maybe there is a better approach.

Sorry if my scope is too wide or vague but i been searching for an answer to my question without success.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98734/what-is-separation-of-concerns

Answer (score 0):

You best put the handler on the container and set data attributes of the anchor to run element specific code.

Some pseudo code:

```
$(document.body).on("click"=function(e){
  var eventToTrigger = e.target.getAttribute("data-trigger");
  if(eventToTrigger){
    someMediator.trigger(eventToTrigger,{
      eventSource:e
    });
  }
});
```

Then your anchor can look like this:

```
<a href="#" data-trigger="showMore">Show More</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) i think its the right way to don't write the javascript blocks inside each retrieved html.
In case you come across with the same doubt, im following this tutorial as introduction [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZSjvWtUxYk](http://backbonejs.org/)